# Is there any difference between Y component of YUV and converted grey component of RGB image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In image processing, I want to compute PSNR of two images.

- I found a code that computes PSNR of YUV videos.
- I know I can convert YUV to avi or other container formats. But I
  have numerous videos, so converting will be wasting time.
- Can I take my RGB videos and after converting them into grey scale,
  calculate PSNR?

Do grey scale of a colored image or Y component of YUV image are same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it should be the same, as long as we are speaking about Y' (luma).

Of course it depends on how the conversion to Grayscale is made, but MATLAB default `rgb2gray` employs the standard weighted sum. From [the documentation](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html):

> `rgb2gray` converts RGB values to grayscale values by forming a weighted sum of the R, G, and B components:
>
> `0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B`

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Conversion_to.2Ffrom_RGB) the standard ([BT.601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._601)) Y' of the Y'UV color space is computed with the same weights:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Conversion from RGB to grayscale is usually achieved by calculating a weighted average of R,G and B values.

Different standards use different weights. If you use the same weights you get comparable values.